# Fragment callbacks are not called when screen is OFF

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I've ran into an strange problem involving my fragments callback flow on an Android app. Here is the problem:

I receive a list of messages, some of then are read and others are new, I separate then so the unread ones are put into a list of unread messages, the rest are put each one in a separate tab, all tabs are composed of fragments, a list fragment for the unread an a detail fragment for each read message.

So when I finish receiving the list and try to remount my tabs, the app behaves differently when the screen is ON and when it's OFF. I've put a Log in each important call of my flow, here are the two scenarios I described:

Screen ON:

```
12-18 12:07:09.704: D/MainActivity(14178): oncreate
12-18 12:07:10.134: D/MainActivity(14178): refreshListAfterPush
12-18 12:07:10.395: D/MainActivity(14178): refresh
12-18 12:07:10.445: D/MainActivity(14178): onStart
12-18 12:07:10.445: D/MainActivity(14178): onResume
12-18 12:07:10.875: D/JOBLIST(14178):      onAttach
12-18 12:07:10.875: D/JOBLIST(14178):      onCreate: joblist created
12-18 12:07:10.885: D/JOBLIST(14178):      FINISHED ON CREATE
12-18 12:07:10.905: D/JOBLIST(14178):      onCreateView JobListFragment
12-18 12:07:10.915: D/JOBLIST(14178):      FINISHED ON CREATE VIEW
12-18 12:07:10.915: D/JOBLIST(14178):      ONRESUME
12-18 12:07:15.449: D/MainActivity(14178): adding new itens to list
```

So all my fragments are correctly added to the list and everything works fine, this is the desired behavior.

When the screen is OFF and my activity receives an intent due to a GCM push:

```
12-18 12:11:26.504: D/MainActivity(14353): oncreate
12-18 12:11:26.865: D/MainActivity(14353): refreshListAfterPush
12-18 12:11:27.175: D/MainActivity(14353): refresh
12-18 12:11:27.255: D/MainActivity(14353): onStart
12-18 12:11:27.255: D/MainActivity(14353): onResume
12-18 12:11:27.315: D/MainActivity(14353): onPause
12-18 12:11:27.315: D/MainActivity(14353): elapsed between resume and pause: 0
12-18 12:11:32.190: D/MainActivity(14353): adding new itens to list
12-18 12:11:32.200: D/JOBLIST(14353):      UPDATE LIST JOB
```

For some reason when the screen is OFF the onCreate and onCreateView of the Fragment is not called, so when I try to update it, some objects are not initialized, resulting in a crash.

The Fragment is created and added in the onCreate of the MainActivity, that is called in both cases, as seen in the logs.

What i'm I missing, is there any difference between an activity initialization when the screen is visible and when it is not?

**EDIT:**

In an older version of the app, the onCreate of the activity is called just after the activity calls its onResume callback and everything happens normally. Is there any asynchronicity in this flow of callbacks?

**NOTE:**

I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to serve some SherlockFragment.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what i was doing was wrong, and I know that. Having the model inside the view(fragment code) is incorrect, and I should not expect it to work this way.

But it really did work in the previous version of my app.

What I found out in the end is that depending on the Android API target chosen, the behavior of the callbacks are different, and were a bit wrong in earlier versions of Android.

When I built my app targeting Android 4.0, the fragment's onCreate callback was called even if it did not come visible in the screen. In Android 4.4 (that I used when I asked this question), the behavior is more correct, but it spoiled the functionality I was expecting, resulting in a bunch of NullPointerExceptions.

Well, I did not find any official documentation about that, so I'm just posting to tell what i found, in case someone else is in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. Think about it. You don't need to update de screen view, consuming energy and time, if nobody is going to see it. This is part of the phylosophy (save battery) in almost every mobile device.

In your case the fragment is not being attached because a fragment is in some way, a piece of view.

Comment: I'd make sense if it did not work when the call is made with the application already running, because in this case the behavior is correct